# count number of columns that have data for each row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have table with 8 columns, and 5000+ rows.

I needed help writing t-sql select that would count for each row the number of columns that are not null.

Comment: Do you want specifically **TSQL (Transact SQL)** or just any MS SQL Server code whether it's valid TSQL or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, replacing the two occurrences of "Catalog" with the name of your table. This has been tested successfully on SQL Server 2008 R2 Dev Edition in the default ReportServer database.

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max)
SET @Sql = 'SELECT 0'

SELECT
    @Sql = @Sql + '
+ CASE WHEN [' + [sys].[columns].[name] + '] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'
FROM [sys].[columns]
WHERE [sys].[columns].[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('Catalog')
    AND [sys].[columns].is_nullable = 1

SET @Sql = @Sql + '
AS [NullValuesCount] FROM [Catalog]'

PRINT @Sql

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

Note that this approach is susceptible to a SQL-Injection attack if you can't trust the source of the column names (e.g. if end users can causes columns to be created with names under their control).

Comment: Is this valid tsql (I'm going off of the OP's tags)? I thought this is MSSQLServer only?

Comment: @DVK: Yep, I've tested it in SQL Server 2008 Dev Edition using the default ReportServer database

Comment: @Daniel - I meant that this would not work in other T-SQL supporting servers, e.g. Sybase, because I am not sure if dynamic SQL (sp_executesql) is part of Transact SQL standard

Comment: @DVK: Interesting - I wasn't aware any other DBMS used T-SQL. `sp_executesql` can certainly be replaced with `EXEC` but I don't know if there are any other SQL-Server-only'isms in there.

Comment: exec doesn't support the content being drawn from a variable outside of SQL server. I think there's some funky way of doing it in Sybase as well but it certainly isn't part of standard TSQL. Mind you, it's still a good answer, just not T-SQL one. I suspect the OP didn't care about TSQL too much and only put that tag in error, since he accepted your answer.

Comment: @Daniel - "Transact-SQL (T-SQL) is Microsoft's and Sybase's proprietary extension to SQL". If you recall, originally MS SQL Server and Sybase server were actaully the same product that got forked. TSQL predates that fork.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Transact SQL (not using dynamic SQL call which is not part of TSQL):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN c1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  + CASE WHEN c2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  + CASE WHEN c3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  + CASE WHEN c4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  + CASE WHEN c5 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  + CASE WHEN c6 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  + CASE WHEN c7 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  + CASE WHEN c8 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM T
```