# Count number of occurences of a value in different columns in *one* row/record

Tags: php, mysql, count

I might be doing this the wrong way when I set up the tables?
I'm using mysql & php. Loads of googleing only shows how to count how many times a value appears in several rows, I want check for a value in many different columns but in the same record. (I think this: [count number of columns that have data for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286711/count-number-of-columns-that-have-data-for-each-row) just might be about the same thing, maybe? but I don't get it.)

I have a table with goals that I hope to work on and achieve every day. So for every day I wish to mark: "success" or "fail". And insert is working great. How ever I'm looking for a way to calculate the number of success& number of fails of "today", to show the right kind of smiley which will be encouraging or sad depending on number of fails and number of successes.

For example:

```
ID  date          drinkMoreWater    goToBedEarlier    callADearFriend
1   2012 jan 15   fail              fail              fail
1   2012 jan 16   success           _(still empty)    success
```

So if today is jan 15 the smiley will be very very sad.
If today is jan 16 the smiley will be really really hppy with stars in it's eye's (atleast until I fail goal 2  ;)  )

Comment: How many columns do you need to count and is the set of columns fixed?

Comment: You just get all date & drinkMoreWater onto your PHP code within two arrays , compare the two arrays. Have u tried it that way ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your tables should actually be structured differently to make your life easier:

```
Goals:
ID     Goal
1      drinkMoreWater
2      goToBedEarly
3      callADearFriend

Status:
ID     Status
1      Success
2      Fail

Tracking:
ID     Date      Goal_ID     Status_ID
1      1/1/2012  1           1
1      1/1/2012  3           2
1      1/2/2012  2           1
1      1/2/2012  4           1
```

Now you could easily add goals and status (e.g. 'Working on it') and your table structure does not have to change to accommodate your changes, your queries become a lot simpler as well.

Comment: Was about to post the same, so +1 for this one. Only note is that `Status` is a bit less needed than `Goals` if you look at the current values (`fail`/`success`/`NULL`)

Comment: @TheNail maybe it's an over kill but read my comment and you might see that it could eventually become useful

Comment: I would like to add `4 LimitTimeSpentOnStackOverflow`

Comment: @MGA Thanks, hope the OP see the benefit of this redesign

Comment: @TheNail this one will always have Fail entry in my Tracking table :D

Comment: Will take some time to change it, but I do see the value, and want to do it the "right way". :)  Ty for this!

Comment: Project is completed! If anyone wishes a copy of the final solution just pm me @victoriawagman :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in SQL, you could use a ternary-like construct, like that:

```
SELECT *, 
       (CASE drinkMoreWater WHEN 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     + (CASE goToBedEarlier WHEN 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     + (CASE callADearFriend WHEN 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     AS numberOfSuccesses 
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Select case when sub.smilies = 0 then "very very sad" else 
             case when sub.smilies = 1 then "sad" else "hubby" end
        end as "Number of Smilies"
from
(
     Select case when t.drinkMoreWater  = "fail" then 0 else 1 end +
            case when t.goToBedEarlier  = "fail" then 0 else 1 end +
            case when t.callADearFriend = "fail" then 0 else 1 end as smilies 
     from yourTableName t 
     where date = @date
) sub
```

You will need to handle the empty strings, and work around these case statements.
This solution is for your current design but you better off consider the redesign suggested by [@BassamMehanni 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870831/count-number-of-occurences-of-a-value-in-different-columns-in-one-row-record/8870908#8870908)

Comment: Why the nested select? The inner one will do all by itself.

Comment: @TedHopp, I added the outer select to enclose in it the outer case statement to be more readable

Comment: I tried it, but I must've done sth wrong, and redesign is in process!